# Android UI MaterialCardView not displaying shadow on all sides

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shadow, materialcardview

I am using a MaterialCardView to display the following expected layout.

IOS screen shot, expected UI

[image]

But on Android side it looks like this. Android screenshot, shadow does not appear on all sides, mainly on the top

[image]

This is my code for this.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:strokeWidth="@dimen/cds_dimen_1dp"
    app:strokeColor="#D9D9D9"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/cds_dimen_4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cds_dimen_8dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cds_dimen_6dp">
[...]

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

What is that I need to do to achieve this?

this is an item_layout_row for a recyclerview

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_reason"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cds_dimen_20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cds_dimen_20dp"/>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean from those images, but if I'm understanding you correctly, Android's shadows are not even on all sides. They are rendered from two light sources – ambient light, and an overhead spotlight – so a shadow's bottom side will be darker than its top, and the difference will become more noticeable as the `View` gets closer to the bottom of the screen. If that is what you mean, you could disable the uneven spotlight effect by setting the theme attribute `<item name="android:spotShadowAlpha">0.0</item>`, but that will apply to all `View`s in the `Activity`/`Dialog`.

Comment: You might also need to increase the ambient's alpha, 'cause it's _really_ light by default: `<item name="android:ambientShadowAlpha">0.039</item>`. That value has a range of `0.0`-`1.0`.

Comment: For completeness' sake, I should also mention that you could disable the spotlight by setting the `android:outlineSpotShadowColor` attribute to transparent on a `<View>` or in a style, but that's not available until API level 28, Pie. (After James' edit, I see that I did understand you correctly.)

Comment: @MikeM. yes the issue is -- on ios, see a shadow uniformly distributed on all sides. but on android primarily on the top side, there is no shadow. I am not understanding how can i achieve this

Comment: You would set those alpha attributes in your `Activity`'s theme: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EEIOM41HncFBrYOIQNUexLFOdRgRenRZ/view?usp=share_link. Those values, and increasing the elevation a bit, gives results like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tafHn.png. (Probably don't need to worry about the `outlineSpotShadowColor` for now, especially since it would only work on Pie and above.)

Comment: Oh...i don't have flexibility to add in the activity theme...i can however try to add on the fragment theme and see. But 1 question, was wondering if by some means adding some properties in the material card in the xml would hve been ideal actually.

Comment: No, I would've suggested that first. Also, the alpha values are actually settings for the `Window`'s renderer, so they will only have effect if set in the `Activity`'s initial theme, unfortunately, and they will apply to all of the `View`s it contains. Btw, if the native shadows aren't going to work for your design, you might be able to find a library that draws its own shadows which might be suitable. Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I just realized: if your `Fragment` is a `DialogFragment`, that is a separate `Window`, so you would be able to apply those alpha attributes with its own theme. (Sorry if I'm confusing things, here.)

Comment: Hi @MikeM.- I tried adding the style to the BottomSheetDialogFragment. This is what did and get. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E16y7BS8fOVglT5H4QUZ-76M7Li0-kOpWRZMHbJQMYI/edit

Comment: My example increased the elevation, too; at least double, IIRC.

Comment: @MikeM.- can you please post the code? I mean are you doing any additional codes for this

Comment: I would assume that since you can't change the `Activity`'s theme, you didn't set `bottomSheetDialogTheme` there, so it's not being applied. You'll need to do it in code, if you haven't already. I put together a minimal example of what your setup seems to be: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EFDVVvCkp95acBH-GzeYYEl8ZkShAVT4/view?usp=share_link. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZjXE.png.

Comment: Hi @MikeM. - Thanks a ton for your help man ! You saved me ! After applying the code, this is what I see 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UJ6wn7vjBTWLrVCZc1qkrL4SPeywd2QtVOgc1si0qFg/edit 

I will let it be like this as of now until the UX guy chases me ! But thanks a ton man !